# how to bind IGrouping To data grid which contain dataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I'm new at wpf and I have a problem.
I have 2 model:
model 1 is Student and model 2 is Course.
I want to show for each student what is the courses he take in combobox, And I don't know how to bind IGrouping to DataGrid which contain DataTemplate.

This is my code:

```
 public IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,Student_Course>>student_courses { get; set; }
 public P_Show_Student()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load_Student();
    }

    private void Load_Student()
    {
        using (var db = new DataBaseContext())
        {
            var registerd_student = db.Student_Course.Include(x => x.Student_Id_FK).Include(x => x.Course_Id_FK).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Student_Id).ToList();
            student_courses = registerd_student as IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Student_Course>>;
            Student.ItemsSource = student_courses;

        }
    }
```

And this is My Model:

```
    public class Student_Course
    {
    [Key]
    public int Student_Course_Id { get; set; }

    public int Course_Id { get; set; }

    public int Student_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Course_Id))]
    public Course Course_Id_FK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Student_Id))]
    public Student Student_Id_FK { get; set; }

}
```

And This my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Student" AlternatingRowBackground = "LightBlue"  
     AlternationCount = "2" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Student_Id_FK.Student_Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Student_Id_FK.Full_Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number Phone" Binding="{Binding Student_Id_FK.Phone_Number}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Collage" Binding="{Binding Student_Id_FK.Collage}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Courses" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding student_courses, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}" 
                            SelectedValuePath="Student_Id"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Course_Id_FK.Coures_Name"
                        
                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                        IsEditable="False"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The problem is when I load this Page the ComboBox Empty and doesn't show anything.
thanx in advance.

Comment: I solve the problem by editing the ComboBox Property:
     `<ComboBox 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                DisplayMemberPath="Course_Id_FK.Coures_Name"
                                SelectedIndex="0"
                                />`